# debian mysql server always down

Tags: mysql, debian

I am hosting a mysql server in a debian 6.0.4 server hosted in linode, the new data is frequently written into the mysql server using R, about 30-40 "write" per minute, about 7 hours a day, 5 days a week.

Recently I found that the mysql server seem to down frequently, always give me error that mysql server cannot be connected through socket. I wonder if this is caused by my high demand to my mysql server, and if this can be solved.

I am definitely a newbie in manage server. Please let me know if I need to provide additional information for this question in order to get it solved. Thanks.

#### update 01

the error message is :

```
enter code here`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Then I tried the method mentioned [here](http://anthologyoi.com/computers/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socketerror.html), then run `sudo mysqld restart` again, and gives me a different error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
```

Comment: 30-40 writes per minute is as far from being "high demand" as my beard is from being a supernova.

Comment: Also, post the exact error message that you see.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your MySQL server being down will very likely be in the MySQL error log. It is located, on Debian based systems, at `/var/log/mysql.log`.

---

## Edit 1

That sounds like MySQL isn't even running. See if it's running at all with `ps aux | grep mysqld | grep -v grep` and then see if it's listening on any network ports `netstat -lntp | grep mysqld`

If the log file is empty, make sure that the mysql.log is owned by the user that MySQL runs as. If it isn't, then `chown` it to be owned by the MySQL user. A log might also be in `/var/log/mysqld/mysql.log`.

Comment: I tried to view the `/var/log/mysql.log`, it is empty, and I just `mysqld restart` my server, will this be the reason that the log file is emptied?

Comment: check our /var/log/syslog  by default it will log there unless your my.cnf says other wise

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server` it will remove mysql 
after that install it again using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`